# Differential of an integration

Tags: integration, derivatives, convex-analysis

I have $N$ different linear functions defined by,

$$y_i = a_i - b_i Q_i, \forall i \in [1, 2, \cdots N]$$

Which I want to aggregate. Here, $a_i$, $b_i$ are constants, and are $\in \mathbb{R}^+$. I can represent the variable $Q_i$ as $\alpha \beta_i$, where, $\beta_i$ is also a constant.

Essentially, my aggregated function $Y(Q)$ and is defined as:

$$Y(Q) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i - \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_i \beta_i$$

And, I have defined, $Q$ to be $= \alpha\sum_{i=1}^{N}\beta_i$

Then, my question is can I write as follows?

$$\frac{d}{d\alpha} \int_0^{\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i}  Y(Q) dQ = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i \right) Y( \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i ) $$

Comment: Some context would probably help. In particular, what are $\alpha$,$\beta$,$S$, ...

Comment: Your definition of $y_i$ as a function is still very confused. What is the unknown ?

Comment: $\alpha$ is the variable.

Comment: Well ... I still think it is extremely confusing. But for what it's worth, I did the computation and found the same result as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \alpha = \dfrac{Q}{\sum_{i=1}^N \beta_i} $$.

So, 
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha} \int_0^{\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i}  Y(Q) dQ = 
\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i\Bigg)\frac{d}{d Q} \int_0^{Q}  Y(Q) dQ =
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i \right) Y( \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i )$$

The second equality follows because of the second fundamental theorem of calculus. Unless I am missing something, you are right.